# Difficulty following chain rule segment for proof of a Euler-Lagrange energy conservation proof

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics, chain-rule, euler-lagrange-equation

If you take a look at the lecture notes I'm not too sure how he's used the chain rule to rewrite the derivative in terms of $t'$ rather than epsilon.

Thanks in advance, would've typed it up but didn't want to make any mistakes transcribing and I think they're pretty readable

[Screenshot from online notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6bdw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems OP's question is spurred by the fact that it is implicitly understood that $\frac{\partial}{\partial t^{\prime}}$ is an *explicit* (as opposed to a *total*) $t^{\prime}$-derivative.